# Why is my second row being placed between the two opposing floats

Tags: html, css

Why is the second row with selector #message slipping in between the opposing floats.

My thought, the reason for this behaviour is that when you float in this case one to the
left and one to the right the space in between is free available space which the second row 
take advantage of that's the reson according to my knowledge.
The floated element to the left and right will only take up as much space as they need and 
they are considered to be block element.

If I remove the comment on clear:both; in selector #message then it works and that is
because you clering the #message element saying this element is not allowed to sit between 
an element that is floating.

I just want to confirm with you if my thought of understanding is about right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Testing</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <style type="text/css" media="screen">
                 body 
                 {
                 margin: 0;
                 padding: 0;
                 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                 font-size: small;
                 text-align: center;
                 width:768px;
                 }

                 #register  
                 {
                     margin: 0;
                     padding: 0;
                     list-style: none;
                     background: yellow;    
                 }

                 #reg 
                 {
                 float: left;
                 margin: 0;
                 padding: 8px 14px;
                 background:red;
                 }

                 #find  
                 {
                  float: right;
                  margin: 0;
                  padding: 8px 14px;
                  background:blue;
                 } 

                 #message 
                 {
                    /*clear:both;*/
                    text-align: center;
                    background: #92B91C;
                 }
             </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <ul id="register">
                <li id="reg">Not registered? <a href="#">Register</a> now!</li>
                <li id="find"><a href="#">Find a store</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="message">
                <p><strong>Special this week:</strong> $2 shipping on all orders! <a 
                        href="#">LEARN MORE</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

//Tony
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

or

```
#message{
    clear: both;
}
```

These are 2 different techniques of clearing your floats. The only reason the message is sitting between your two floats is because space available allows the next element to occupied the empty space - because the floats have been removed from the document flow. To bring things back to normal, you have to clear your floats.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hWgED/1/

In your code only need to uncomment the #message id --> `clear:both`